# Microsoft SQL Server access denied

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have downloaded a backup of a demo database from Microsoft (AdventureWorks2014.bak) in order to follow an online tutorial.

When I am trying to restore the database using the following query:

```
USE [master]

RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2014

FROM disk = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2014.bak'

WITH MOVE 'AdventureWorks2014_data'

TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2014.mdf',

MOVE 'AdventureWorks2014_Log'

TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL   \DATA\AdventureWorks2014.mdf',


REPLACE
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 3176, Level 16, State 1, Line 3

File 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2014.mdf' is claimed by 'AdventureWorks2014_Log'(2) and 'AdventureWorks2014_Data'(1). The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files.

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3

RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

The server is running locally on my system and I'm logged in as an administrator. I've tried to do the following to no avail:

- Run MSSMS as an administrator
- Give my user full folder permisions of Microsoft SQL folder
- Give my user full permissions under the server permissions
- Made sure the .bak file is not read-only

Yet I'm still getting the error. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Notice "Operating system error 5(Access is denied.)" in the error message. This tells you this is NOT a sql error. It is a Windows permission error. Most likely is that the sql service user does not have proper permission to that file.

Comment: Nevermind, I have found the solution. I was trying to put the log and the data file in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to move data and log into the same directory. Changed it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the file extension of AdventureWorks2014 from .mdf to .ldf in the penultimate line of your code.

File extension .ldf meant for saving log of database.